# ImageTk attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to change file directory in ImageTk.PhotoImage, what is the method to change attributes and get attributes?

like this:

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "./gi01.png")

img.itemconfigure(file = img.get(file)[:-5] + "2" + ".png")
```

Comment: What do you mean precisely by 'changing file directory' of the PhotoImage? Do you want to move the image file to another directory? Do you want to save the image under another name? Do you want to rename the image file?

Answer (score 0):

There is no method for changing the attributes of an image. Even if there was, changing the directory wouldn't do what you think it should do. The directory is specified as part of the path when creating the image.

As with most objects, you can issue the command `help(img)` to get information about how to interact with that object.